# Google Analytics - Invalid Credentials for v2.4

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

We have existing code that uses v2.4 endpoint to get GA data. The way our application works is the user enters their own credentials (username & password) and the API key and we use them to get data from GA API v2.4. We are using the v2.4 client libraries.

Recently a new GA account user tried to use our program and our code gets a "Invalid Credential" exception from the client library.
The code

```
AnalyticsService asv = new AnalyticsService(string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", CustomName, "MyApp", "2.0"));
asv.setUserCredentials(Username, Password);
Uri uri = new Uri(GetGoogleAnalyticsEndpoint(GAEndpointType.Account));
using (Stream stream = asv.Query(uri)) { //<--**This throws the exception**
```

I can get data for this account when I went the OAuth route. So this would mean the account has access and things are setup fine (apparently). We are going to go OAuth route in a later release; meanwhile we need this to get working.

Would anyone know what could potentially be wrong? What other configuration values I should check? I have compared the working GA account to this non-working one and the console appears the same (except for key values and such).

Thanks.